# Is there a calendar app that supports email reminders?

Tags: email, google-calendar

I use Google sync to coordinate my Google calendar with my iPhone. The iPhone calendar app does not support creating email reminders. Is there an iPhone calendar app that supports creating email reminders so that when I create an event on my iPhone I get an email reminder to my Gmail account?

Comment: Direct push does not work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is no interface in the iPhone calendar app for creating email reminders. Therefore when I create an event on the iPhone I do not get an email reminder. Syncing between Google calendar and my iPhone works fine both ways. That is not the issue.

Comment: Does it have to be an e-mail notification, you van set a reminder which just will *beep beep beep* when it's time.

Comment: Yes, it has to be an email notification. I already get notifications of incoming email on the phone so when Google calendar reminders are sent to email that serves as a reminder of the event on the phone. Plus it's in the email so the event is more visible. I may create the event with my phone but only be near a computer with email (not near the phone) when the reminder is fired.

Comment: Fantastical on the Mac desktop will do this, but as far as I can tell, the iOS version does not.

Comment: If for whatever reason, you can't or don't want to use Google Calendar app or whatever, you could probably set up an automated trigger through IFTTT or another similar service.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Google Calendar app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-calendar-make-most/id909319292?l=en&mt=8) that allows you to add email notifications:

[image: google calendar app email notification]

Go to the event, scroll down a little, tap on "Add a notification"  and then on "Custom"

Answer (score 0):

Calendars 5 by Readdle is the only app I know that does this, but lately the app has been crashing a lot so I can't really recommend it. Now that I use Things for reminders I'm going to try switching away from email reminders and just scheduling items in Things instead.